# Cannot load data into value of select tag in php

Tags: php

I'm trying get value from `select` tag in php.I `foreach` data from an array  but it don't work. How to it work correctly.

**index.php**

```
<?php require 'app/config.php';?> <!-- connect database -->
<?php require 'app/result.php'; ?>
<?php require 'app/function.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
<body>
     <form action="" method="post">

                Khối thi:               
                    <?php $values = &OptionValues(); ?>       
                        <select class="select">
                           <?php foreach($values as $value):?>                 
                               <option value="<?php $value['khoi_thi']; ?>"></option>

                          <?php endforeach;?>
                        </select> 
                   <br/>     

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
require 'config.php'; <!-- connect database -->


function &OptionValues() {
    $fn = array();
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT khoi_thi FROM `2014_khoathi` ");
    $i = 0;
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $fn[$i++] = array($data);

    }
    return $fn; <!-- return an array -->
}

?>
```

**Result what I want:**

```
<select>
   <option value="A1"></option>
   <option value="A2"></option>
   <option value="A3"></option>
   <!-- 3 results if database has 3 rows -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know about the driver you are using is deprecated:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php

I will do it in this simple way with the mysqli driver (actual driver):

```
<?php
    // inside config.php
    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "root","password_here","whatever_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Database Conection Failed: ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }
    // end config.php
    $sql = "SELECT khoi_thi FROM 2014_khoathi";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
?>

<select class = "select">
   <?php 
      while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<option value = '{$row['khoi_thi']}'> {$row['khoi_thi']} </option>";
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Here is with the deprecated mysql driver:

```
<?php
    // inside config.php
    $mysql=mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_mysql', 'password_mysql');
    if (!$mysql) {
        echo 'Database Conection Failed: ';
        exit;
    }
    // end config.php
    $sql = "SELECT khoi_thi FROM 2014_khoathi";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $mysql);
?>
<select class = "select">
  <?php 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
             echo "<option value = '{$row['khoi_thi']}'> {$row['khoi_thi']} </option>";
        }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: **Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php on line 29

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php on line 29**
<br>
line 29: `<?php $sql = "SELECT khoi_thi FROM 2014_khoathi";
                                          $query = $mysqli->query($sql);?>      `

@Jr Jimnz

Comment: added the deprecated functions